# App crashes when there is no delay in LaunchedEffect

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

Why my app crashes when I run this code:

```
val scrollState = rememberLazyListState(0)
var isLastItemVisible by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

LaunchedEffect(scrollState) {
    while (!isLastItemVisible) {
        val lastVisibleItemIndex = scrollState.layoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo.lastOrNull()?.index
        val totalItemsCount = scrollState.layoutInfo.totalItemsCount
        isLastItemVisible = lastVisibleItemIndex != null && lastVisibleItemIndex == totalItemsCount - 1
    }

    onLastItemSeen()
}
```

When I add any delay at last line in loop there is everything right.
I display items in LazyRow.

Comment: Add the crash stacktrace with question . Looks like a stackoverflow error to me ..

Comment: Your while loop doesn't do anything that would change the outcome of the last line, so it will run infinitely and give you a stack overflow.

Comment: There is no crash stacktrace. Answer below is useful, thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's giving ANR not crashing because you are in an infinite loop you can't scroll.

You can use derivedStateOf to check if last item is visible as

```
val isLastItemVisible by remember {
    derivedStateOf {
        val lastVisibleItemIndex = scrollState.layoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo.lastOrNull()?.index
        val totalItemsCount = scrollState.layoutInfo.totalItemsCount
        lastVisibleItemIndex != null && lastVisibleItemIndex == totalItemsCount - 1
    }
}

LaunchedEffect(isLastItemVisible){
    if (isLastItemVisible){
        // Send event here
    }
}
```

or snapshotFlow inside LaunchedEffect that sends event only once

```
// Sends event only once
LaunchedEffect(scrollState) {
    snapshotFlow {
        scrollState.layoutInfo
    }
        .map {
            val lastVisibleItemIndex = it.visibleItemsInfo.lastOrNull()?.index
            val totalItemsCount = it.totalItemsCount
            lastVisibleItemIndex != null && lastVisibleItemIndex == totalItemsCount - 1
        }
        // If it's a one time event filtering it
        .filter { it }
        .distinctUntilChanged()
        .collect {
            println("New Event sent...")
        }
}
```

Or one that sends event every time last item is visible

```
// Sends event every time last item is seen
LaunchedEffect(scrollState) {
    snapshotFlow {
        scrollState.layoutInfo
    }
        .map {
            val lastVisibleItemIndex = it.visibleItemsInfo.lastOrNull()?.index
            val totalItemsCount = it.totalItemsCount
            lastVisibleItemIndex != null && lastVisibleItemIndex == totalItemsCount - 1
        }
        .distinctUntilChanged()
        .collect {visible->
            println("Scroll visible: $visible")
            if (visible){
                println("New Event sent...")
            }

        }
}
```

Also i add a sample to display button on bottom end when last item is visible can be implemented such as

```
@Preview
@Composable
private fun ListSample() {
    val scrollState = rememberLazyListState(0)

    val isLastItemVisible by remember {
        derivedStateOf {
            val lastVisibleItemIndex = scrollState.layoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo.lastOrNull()?.index
            val totalItemsCount = scrollState.layoutInfo.totalItemsCount
            lastVisibleItemIndex != null && lastVisibleItemIndex == totalItemsCount - 1
        }
    }

    Box {
        LazyColumn(
            state = scrollState
        ) {
            items(20) {
                Text(
                    text = "Row $it",
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().padding(8.dp),
                    fontSize = 20.sp
                )
            }
        }

        if (isLastItemVisible) {
            FloatingActionButton(
                modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.BottomEnd).padding(8.dp),
                onClick = {

                },
                content = {
                    Icon(imageVector = Icons.Default.ArrowUpward, contentDescription = null)

                }
            )
        }
    }
}
```